# Index isn't unique for key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried using the index as the key for mapped `<option>` elements in my `render()` function but it still isn't working. It's so odd, I `console.log(activity_type_options)` before I map through just to check if maybe I am reinitializing `activity_type_options` to something else. But the array does not change. The component itself renders three times I can see. But this shouldn't even cause this, right?

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

**Inside render return**

```
 activity_type_options.map(activity => {
      return (
        <option key={activity} value={activity}>
          {activity}
        </option>
      )
    })
```

**activity_type_options**

> ["BLDNG", "EQUIP", "CNSER", "TRNSP", "SFDEV", "STREG", "EXPNS", "RLEST"]

```
class ActivityModal extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const {handleClick} = this.props
    const promise = new Promise(res => {
      res(handleClick({target: {name: this.activity_type.name, value: this.activity_type.value}}))
    })
    promise.then(() => {
      handleClick({target: {name: this.activity.name, value: this.activity.value}})
    })
  }
  render() {
    const {
      showModal,
      toggle,
      activity_type_options,
      activity_options,
      selectedType,
      selectedActivity,
      handleClick,
      saveActivity
    } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          style={{position: 'absolute', top: '100px', left: '50px'}}
          isOpen={showModal}
          toggle={() => toggle()}
          className={this.props.className}
        >
          <ModalHeader toggle={() => toggle()}>New Activity Line</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <div className='form-select'>
              <strong style={{fontSize: '14px'}}>Activity Type</strong>
              <select
                ref={element => (this.activity_type = element)}
                style={{fontWeight: '900', fontSize: '12px'}}
                id='activity_type'
                onChange={e => handleClick(e)}
                className='no-radius'
                name='selectedType'
              >
                {activity_type_options.map((activity, index) => {
                  return (
                    <option key={index} value={activity}>
                      {activity}
                    </option>
                  )
                })}
              </select>
              <strong style={{fontSize: '14px'}}>Activity</strong>
              <select
                ref={element => (this.activity = element)}
                style={{fontWeight: '900', fontSize: '12px'}}
                id='activity'
                onChange={e => handleClick(e)}
                className='no-radius'
                name='selectedActivity'
              >
                {activity_options
                  .filter(option => selectedType === option.activityRefName)
                  .map(activity => {
                    return <option value={activity.activityTypeName}>{activity.activityTypeName}</option>
                  })}
              </select>
              <strong style={{fontSize: '14px'}}>Activity Desc</strong>
              <input value={selectedActivity} disabled />
              <strong style={{fontSize: '14px'}}>Activity Name</strong>
              <input disabled value={selectedActivity} />
            </div>
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color='secondary' onClick={() => toggle()}>
              Cancel
            </Button>{' '}
            <Button color='primary' onClick={saveActivity}>
              OK
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ActivityModal
```

Comment: Provide complete code. Maybe the error happens in other part of your app.

Comment: Your code has 2 instances of `map` for activity, and your second one doesn't have `key` property set.

Comment: I just saw that when I added the code. *Smashes head into keyboard*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component have 2 maps, and the second one is not using `key` props. Then, you should change it:

```
{activity_options.filter(option => selectedType === option.activityRefName)
              .map(activity => {
                return <option key={activity.activityTypeName} value={activity.activityTypeName}>{activity.activityTypeName}</option>
              })}
```

Comment: I was typing out the solution, but lemme give you the credit =]. Gimme 6 min

Comment: @user10204157 I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be in your second `<select>` where the `<option>` elements are not rendered with a `key` prop.

Try revising your code so that the index of the array item ([as passed via the second map callback parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters)) is used for the `key` of options in the second select, as you have with the first:

```
<select ref={element => (this.activity = element)}
        style={{fontWeight: '900', fontSize: '12px'}}
        id='activity'
        onChange={e => handleClick(e)}
        className='no-radius'
        name='selectedActivity'> {

    activity_options
    .filter(option => selectedType === option.activityRefName)
    .map((activity, index) => (

        <option key={index} 
                value={activity.activityTypeName}> { activity.activityTypeName }
        </option> 
    ))
}              
</select>
```

Comment: Well, he clearly mentioned that he already tried that option :\

Comment: @kinduser, no, He did not. He'd  tried it just for one of the `map()` that the code have

Comment: @mthrsj Dacre already edited his post so you are unable to see how did it look like at the beginning ;\

Comment: @kinduser got it

Comment: thanks @kinduser and mthrsj - just tided up the formatting to the code sample a bit. Hopefully that makes the answer a bit clearer